# When you press the CE button... How can I change the value of Anum?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you press the CE button...

Implementing a function called ce().
When I press ce, I want to take the Anum variable again and calculate it, but the Bnum value keeps changing...

How can I change the value of Anum?

```js
var num = 0;
var kiho;
var flag = false;
var Anum = 0;
var Cnum = 0;


function backDo() {
  total.value = total.value.substring(0, total.value.length - 1);

  if (total.value.length == 0) {
    clean();
  }
}

function add(a) {
  if (flag == false) {
    total.value = "";
    flag = true;
  }
  total.value += a;
}

function cal(b) {
  Anum = document.getElementById("total").value;
  kiho = b;
  return total.value = "";
}

function ce() {
  //total.value = ""; 
  document.getElementById("total").value = "";
  Cenumber();
}

function Cenumber() {
  Cnum = document.getElementById("total").value;

}

function merge() {

  //Anum = document.getElementById("total").value; 
  //Cnum = Anum;
  Cnum = Anum;
  var Bnum = document.getElementById("total").value;

  var result;

  switch (kiho) {

    case '+':
      result = Number(Anum) + Number(Bnum);
      //document.getElementById("total").value = result;
      total.value = result;
      break;

    case '-':
      result = Number(Anum) - Number(Bnum);
      //document.getElementById("total").value = result;
      total.value = result;
      break;

    case '*':
      result = Number(Anum) * Number(Bnum);
      //document.getElementById("total").value = result;
      total.value = result;
      break;

    case '/':
      result = Number(Anum) / Number(Bnum);
      //document.getElementById("total").value = result;
      total.value = result;
      break;
  }
}

function clean() {
  if (flag == true) {
    flag = false;
    document.getElementById("total").value = "0";
  }
}

function plminus() {
  total.value = -1 * total.value;
  return total.value;
}

function tan() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.tan((total.value * 3.141592) / 180);
  }
  return total.value;
}

function sin() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.sin((total.value * 3.141592) / 180);
  }
  return total.value;
}

function cos() {

  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.cos((total.value * 3.141592) / 180);
  }
  return total.value;
}

function abs() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.abs(total.value);
  }
  return total.value;
}

function tenpow() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.pow(10, total.value);
  }
  return total.value;
}

function twopow() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.pow(2, total.value);
  }
  return total.value;
}

function pactorial() {
  let result = 1;
  for (let i = total.value; i >= 1; i--) {
    result = result * i;
    total.value = result;
  }
  return result;
}



function boon() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = 1 / total.value;
  }
  return total.value;
}

function root() {
  if (total.value.length < 19) {
    total.value = Math.sqrt(total.value);
  }

  return total.value;
}



function jegob() {
  total.value = Math.pow(total.value, 2);
  return total.value;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="total" value=0 style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;"></td>
      <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="button" style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value="tan" onclick="tan()">
            <input type="button" style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value="sin" onclick="sin()">
            <input type="button" style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value="cos" onclick="cos()">
            <input type="button" style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value="abs" onclick="abs()">
            <input type="button" style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value="!" onclick="pactorial()">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='1/n' onclick="boon()">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='x²' onclick="jegob()">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='√' onclick="root()">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='10n' onclick="tenpow()">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='2n' onclick="twopow()">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=7 onclick=a dd(7)>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=8 onclick=a dd(8)>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=9 onclick=a dd(9)>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='X' onclick="cal('*')">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='CE' onclick="ce()">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=4 onclick="add(4)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=5 onclick="add(5)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=6 onclick="add(6)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='-' onclick="cal('-')">
            <input type="button" style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value="back" onclick="backDo()">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=1 onclick="add(1)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=2 onclick="add(2)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=3 onclick="add(3)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='+' onclick="cal('+')">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='+/-' onclick="plminus()">
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='/' onclick="cal('/')">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value=0 onclick="add(0)">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='.' onclick="add('.')">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='=' onclick="merge()">
            <input type='button' style="width:45pt;height:45pt;font-size: 20px;font-weight:bold;" value='C' onclick="clean()">
          </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what value you want `Anum` to be, but `document.getElementById("total").value = "";` followed by `Cnum =  document.getElementById("total").value;` inside `Cenumber();` means `Cnum` is going to be an empty string as well every time, which is maybe not what you want it to do.